# I want to replace the text in html by using "conetnt" but doesn't work

Tags: html, css

div
{ border: none !important; width: 400px; margin: auto; background-color: #eee !important; text-indent: -9999px;}

div::before{content: 'test';color: black;}

Answer (score 0):

The ::before and ::after attribute don't change the main tag's content, but rather they add content before or after it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before